# No apt-get functions working, have tried almost all fixes but none work?

Tags: apt

I got the classic requires installation of unsupported packages. I was told to fix this with

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

So I copy/pasted into the terminal, and it worked as normal. Then my cat walked on <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> (KDE4) and closed the window roughly 75% through the upgrade. I can no longer install non-tarball packages.
I don't even have Alien.

Comment: I also cannot try to update or upgrade

Comment: Please try `apt-get -f install`. Post the errors you got.

Comment: Please at least post the solutions you've tried, this question is unanswerable without more detail!

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it:
`sudo apt-get autoclean`

Or
`sudo apt-get clean`